# Refresh a page with new div grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a grid of divs that, when mouseentered change color. Then, when the a button is clicked and new number is entered to then generate a new grid with a side length of that many divs. I'm new to javascript and jQuery and can't figure out why my code won't generate the divs.

here's my script

```
$('.block').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});

function newGrid(x) {
    for (i = 0; i > x * x; i++) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="block"></div>');
    }
    $('.block').height(960 / );
    $('.block').width(960 / );
}

function clearContainer() {
    $('.block').remove();
}

function askGrid() {
    var num = prompt("enter box length");
    clearContainer();
    newGrid(num);
}

function firstGrid() {
    newGrid(16);


    $('#reset').click(function () {
        askGrid();
    });
} 

$(document).ready(firstGrid);
```

here's my css

```
.container {
    margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
    height: 960px;
    width: 960px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.block {
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#reset {
    display:block;
    padding:5px 20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

html has a css reset and in the body i have a button with id="reset" and a div with class="container"

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

- The slash when setting height and width is wrong (either is 960 divided by something or just 960)
- The for loop is wrong: it should be

`for (i = 0; i < x * x; i++)`

- And the css thing is not going to apply since there are no .block elements when executed. You should probably move it into `newGrid`

Comment: Thanks alot! in the copy of the script an 'x' accidentally got left out of the 960/ .

This works perfectly. Those three things were all that needed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug here `for (i = 0; i > x * x; i++)` it should be `i < x`.
And im not sure what this is

`$('.block').height(960 / );
 $('.block').width(960 / );`

you can set the height and width respectively in the css

Also you need to this for the `mouseenter` event to work

```
 $('.container').on('mouseenter','.block',function () {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
 });
```

Since the items added are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to jquery, a world of excitement and pain!

This code

```
$('.block').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});
```

binds the hover function to all existing `.block` elements on the page when it is run. It's at the top of your script so it'll execute once, binding this property to all `.block` elements when the page loads, but not to `.block` elements created after. To fix this add it inside your "newGrid" function so it rebinds each new element as they are created.

In your loop, you want `for (i = 1; i < x * x; i++)`, starting index from 1 rather than 0, or else you'll have an off by 1 error and create an extra box.

To set the proper heights of .block, you want to divide your .container's dimentions by x, the size of block:

```
$('.block').height(960 / x);
$('.block').width(960 / x);
```

The following are general programming tips:

- As a good practice, functions should have a specific job and only do that job. I moved the clearContainer call to inside newGrid, because it should be the function that builds the new grid that clears the old one, not the one called askGrid. askGrid should do as it is named, and only ask for your new grid dimension.
- You should do a validation on the number received through askGrid. If the user types something that isn't a number, or a negative number, or 0, you shouldn't start making boxes or newGrid will break. I added a loop to keep asking for a size until a proper dimension is provided, but you can chose your behaviour.
- I changed the variable "x" to "block_length" since variables should be given names indicative of that they mean, so that there aren't a bunch of mysterious variables all over the place called x, y, z that you can't tell what they mean from a glance.

Demo in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jsg1h298/2)!

Comment: this does get the original 16x16 grid to form which is great, but there's a missing one at the bottom right and the 'reset' button doesn't for a grid with the parameters of the prompt number.